# Does Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2010 include ASP.NET in the Install?

Tags: tfs

Does Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2010 has ASP.NET included when installing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but TFS refuses to install on a machine without IIS, which in turn brings ASP.NET anyway.

HTH!
Thomas

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Actually I would like to install SharePoint and it needs ASP.NET and the available edition I have on x64 is only TFS!